# Does $\|(I-A)^{-1}\|_{2} \leq 1/(1-\|A\|_{2})$ holds for matrices with spectral radius smaller then 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, matrix-equations

Given a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix matrix $A$, if its spectral radius $0<\rho(A)<1$, does the inequality $\|(I-A)^{-1}\|_{2} \leq 1/(1-\|A\|_{2})$ hold true?

$\|A\|_{2}$ denotes maximum eigenvalue of A.

If it is correct can somebody give me link to the proof for this inequality?

Comment: As pointed out in the answer below, this is obviously false in this form because the RHS can be negative.

Comment: Does the edit above adds some more clarification to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive semidefinite, norm of $A$ is the same as spectral radius of $A$. Thus

$$\|(I-A)^{-1}\|=\|I+A+A^2+\dots\|\leqslant 1+\|A\|+\|A\|^2+\dots=\frac1{1-\|A\|}.$$

Comment: By $\|\cdot\|_2$, the OP presumably means the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, and I don't think this is multiplicative.

Comment: I should have made my question more clear. $0< \rho(A) < 1$.

Comment: @RohitShukla I'm not quite sure either what norm are you refering to. Could you define it in the question?

Comment: @AmirSagiv I am referring to the spectra radius or 2-norm of a matrix. My matrix is forming a converging series as pointed out by the answer.

Comment: That argument works for any algebra norm (ie,any subadditive and submultiplicative norm).